# How to define path for use with /input, such that TeXStudio can detect the location of the file using global command

Tags: compiling, texstudio, input, include, paths

**Background**

I am writing a large document (main.tex) with several chapters (Introduction.tex, LiteratureReview.tex, etc). I use TeXStudio to compile the document. Each chapter is included using /input (I prefer /input over /include to avoid clear pages and for speed). The chapters are stored in a folder (Chapters) in the same directory as main.tex. If I hardcode the path of the chapters as follows:

```
/input{./Chapters/Introduction}
```

the chapter is added to the main document just fine. TeXstudio shows the structure of the document on the left, and due to the usage of /input, there is a link to the file Introduction.tex (and the rest of the chapters).

[image: Example working well with hardcoded path]

**My problem**

I have different versions of the chapters, which I store in a different folder (Chapters_v2, Chapters_v3, etc.), but the chapters have the same name in every folder. This allows me to define a global path at the beginning of the document:

```
\newcommand{\chapterpath}{./Chapters} % Uncomment if I want this path
\newcommand{\chapterpath}{./Chapters_v2} % Uncomment if I want this path
```

Which I uncomment depending on the version I want to use. Then I may input the file using

```
/input{\chapterpath/Introduction}
```

The document compiles fine, but now TeXStudio no longer recognises the path of the chapters, because it does not understand what \chapterpath is.

[image: Example not working well with global path]

Overall, the lost functionality using a global path is:

1. If I click on the document on the left in the structure that TeXStudio identifies, TeXStudio does not know where the file is located.
2. If I open one of the chapter files, right-click anywhere in the document and select "Go to PDF", it does not know which pdf to use.

How do I define a global path and use it such that the above 2 functionalities are not lost?

Comment: Good question but I fear there won't be a satisfying answer. Even with un-TeXified paths TeXstudio sometimes doesn't recognize the correct file for me. Using a macro that might be changed somewhere (unlikely but technically possible) it will not an easy feat for TeXstudio without it actually processing your document with TeX. You could use a toggle, e.g. `\ifversiontwoofmychapters \input{Chapters_V2/file.tex}\else\input{Chapters/file.tex}\fi` but that is far from satisfying itself.